# Copy text from a table cell (td) with Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I'm very new to Selenium and would really appreciate help.

I need to learn how to copy text, particularly from a table from a specific website: https://aca.tampagov.net/citizenaccess/Default.aspx#
(Go to url --> Search --> Building Permits --> click search button).

You can finds a table at the bottom of the page.

The first row in column "Record Type" has text "Commercial Utility Application". If I want to copy the text what I thought I should do is get the xpath which is

```
//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_lblType"]
```

So I would have something like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]').text()
```

But this gives me and error. What am I doing wrong here? And how would I be able to copy texts from such tables?

**EDIT**

So here's what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-81-4e51d9229198>", line 1, in <module>
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* [@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]').text()


File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 387, in find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)


File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 957, in find_element
'value': value})['value']


File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)


File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)


NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]"}

(Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: That table is in an iframe, you need to switch to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is in `iframe`, so you have to switch to it before you can interact with this table. This code snippet will help you to do it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='ACAFrame']")))
# do your stuff
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]').text()
print(text)
driver.switch_to.default_content() # switch back to default content
```

PS: since in the page there is only one table, you can simplify your xPath from:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]
```

to:

```
//tbody/tr[3]/td[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve text Commercial Utility Application, you should try -

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_lblType")).getText();
```